# The method '[]' was called on null while login

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication

**Hello there! while login I am getting the error  "Tried calling: " I have already uploaded the code and error below it worked fine for few days and suddenly started showing this error , please check and help I am new to flutter App development I request you to please explain in details or please correct and rewrite the code if possible. I shall be thankful to you.

**usermodal**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'cart_modal.dart';

class UserModel {
  static const ID = "uid";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const EMAIL = "email";
  static const STRIPE_ID = "stripeId";
  static const CART = "cart";
  static const FAVOURITES = "myfavourites";

  String _name;
  String _email;
  String _id;
  String _stripeId;

//  getters
  String get name => _name;

  String get email => _email;

  String get id => _id;

  String get stripeId => _stripeId;

  // public variables
  List<CartItemModel> cart;
  List<CartItemModel> favourites;

  UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    _name = doc.data()[NAME];
    _email = doc.data()[EMAIL];
    _id = doc.data()[ID];
    cart = _convertCartItems(doc.data()[CART] ?? []);
    favourites = _convertFavouritesItems(doc.data()[FAVOURITES] ?? []);

    _stripeId = doc.data()[STRIPE_ID] ?? '';
  }

  List<CartItemModel> _convertCartItems(List cart) {
    List<CartItemModel> convertedCart = [];
    for (Map cartItem in cart) {
      convertedCart.add(CartItemModel.fromMap(cartItem));
    }
    return convertedCart;
  }

  List<CartItemModel> _convertFavouritesItems(List favourites) {
    List<CartItemModel> convertedFavourites = [];
    for (Map favouritesItem in favourites) {
      convertedFavourites.add(CartItemModel.fromMap(favouritesItem));
    }
    return convertedFavourites;
  }
}
```

**userservice**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/modals/cart_modal.dart';
import 'package:vanfly/modals/user_modal.dart';

class UserServices {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String collection = "users";

 createUser(Map<String,dynamic> data) async {
     _firestore.collection(collection).doc(data["uid"]).set(data);
  }

  Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) async =>
      await _firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
        return UserModel.fromDocument(doc);
      });

  void addToCart({String userId, CartItemModel cartItem}) {
    _firestore.collection(collection).doc(userId).update({
      "cart": FieldValue.arrayUnion([cartItem.toMap()])
    });
  }

  void removeFromCart({String userId, CartItemModel cartItem}) {
    _firestore.collection(collection).doc(userId).update({
      "cart": FieldValue.arrayRemove([cartItem.toMap()])
    });
  }

  void addToFavourites({String userId, CartItemModel favouritesItem}) {
    _firestore.collection(collection).doc(userId).update({
      "favourites": FieldValue.arrayUnion([favouritesItem.toMap()])
    });
  }

  void removeFromFavourites({String userId, CartItemModel favouritesItem}) {
    _firestore.collection(collection).doc(userId).update({
      "favourites": FieldValue.arrayRemove([favouritesItem.toMap()])
    });
  }
}
```

**error**

```
E/flutter ( 8296): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 8296): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 8296): Tried calling: []("name")
E/flutter ( 8296): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter ( 8296): #1      new UserModel.fromDocument (package:vanfly/modals/user_modal.dart:32:23)
E/flutter ( 8296): #2      UserServices.getUserById.<anonymous closure> (package:vanfly/services/user_services.dart:15:26)
E/flutter ( 8296): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter ( 8296): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 8296): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8296): #5      UserServices.getUserById (package:vanfly/services/user_services.dart:14:7)
E/flutter ( 8296): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8296): #6      UserProvider._onStateChanged (package:vanfly/providers/user_provider.dart:79:20)
E/flutter ( 8296): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8296):
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `_firestore.collection(collection).doc(id)` doesn't exist, and thus `doc.data()` then returns `null`, which leads to the error message on `_name = doc.data()[NAME];`.

You'll have to decide what you want to do in `getUserById` when the user document doesn't exist.

---

**Update**: So you'll have to change this code:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) async =>
  await _firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
    return UserModel.fromDocument(doc);
  });
```

You'll need to decide what to do here when the document doesn't exit. For example:

```
Future<UserModel> getUserById(String id) async =>
  await _firestore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
    if (doc.exists) { //  check if the document exists
      return UserModel.fromDocument(doc);
    }
    else {
      return null; //  return something that your calling code can handle
    }
  });
```

Comment: hello sir ! I hope you are doing well, actually I have posted 2 -3 queries on stack but no one is replying. I need your help you are the only person who have helped me solving my queries , I am new to flutter Please help me out. I will waiting for your response . Thank you.